# Determine convergence of harmonic series with a minus every third term

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to evaluate the following sum:
$$
1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6}+\ldots
$$
call the sequence $a_k$. That is, the harmonic series, with the sign flipped every third term.

I tried to approach this in two ways. One way is by defining a sequence $b_k = \left(\frac{1}{3k-2} + \frac{1}{3k-1} -\frac{1}{3k}\right)$. Then, we can see that $\sum b_k$ is the series $\sum a_k$ after we gather every three terms. Then, $b_k = \frac{9k^2-2}{3k(3k-2)(3k-1)}$, and $b_k\sim \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{k}$, and therefore $\sum b_k$ diverges. Can I conclude that $\sum a_k$ diverge?

The other way is by partial sums. I concluded the following inequality
$$
S_{3n-2} < S_{3n} < S_{3n-1}
$$
But also, I discovered that $S_{3n-2},S_{3n-1},S_{3n}$ are increasing, and I was unable to find a bound for them.

Now, for the first way, it is kind of implying that the series diverges, since we learned at our calculus class that if $\sum a_n$ converges, then any way of putting brackets will result in a convergence. On the other way, if a series is created by putting brackets in another series with bounded bracket length, then if it is convergent then the original series converges.

Does this series diverge?

Comment: Seeing as $b_k$ did not rearrange the order of the sum, I'm pretty sure that approach is correct.  Also, note that since $\frac 1k\ge \frac 1{k+1}$ for positive $k$, you have $\frac 1{3k-1}\ge \frac 1{3k}$ which means that $\frac 1{3k-2}+\frac 1{3k-1}-\frac 1{3k}\ge \frac 1{3k}$.

Comment: Yes, $\sum b_k$ divergent implies that $\sum a_k$ diverges. This is because $\sum_{j=1}^N b_j=\sum_{j=1}^{3N} a_j$. So divergence of the sum of the $b_j$ means a subsequence of the partial sums of $\sum a_j$ diverges...

Comment: See also [here](http://www.echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?t=83035) for a discussion on the question "does any harmonic series in which less than half the signs are negative diverge (given that the signs are in a regular pattern like every third, or every other, etc.)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $\sum b_k$ diverges is enough to conclude that $\sum a_k$ diverges.  Indeed, if we define the $n$-th partial sum of $\sum a_k$ to be
$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$
then
$$S_{3n} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k.$$
If $S_n$ did converge to some limit $L$, then $S_{3n}$ would also converge to that same limit.  But $S_{3n}$ diverges, so $S_n$ must diverge as well.